# unable to get the correct output pattern in php

Tags: php

i am trying to get this pattern in php:

[image]

i have tried but i i'm unable to produce the output, as my output is coming like :

```
run-project -l php
5
        0
      01
    012
  0123
01234
```

However, the code is:

```
<?php
function print_pattern($num)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
  {
    for($k = $num; $k > $i+1; $k-- )
      {
      echo "  ";
      }
    for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++ )
      {
      echo $j;
      }
  echo "\n";
  }
}
$num = (int)readline();
print_pattern($num);
?>
```

Comment: What is the logic for this pattern? I can see it's printing numbers sequentially, but I'm guessing it's X number lines of an increasing number of numbers? (first line has 2 numbers, second line has 3, third line has 4, etc)

Comment: $j is counting from 0 every line. try `echo $j+$I`

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is to have numbers printed on each line in an incremental order

> 12   First line 2 Numbers
>
> 345  Second Line 3 numbers (Continued from First line)
>
> 6789 Third Line 4 numbers (Continued from Second line)
>
> and goes on.....

```
 <?php 

function print_pattern($num)
{
  $breaker = 2; // since you want the first line to have 2 Numbers
  $ticker = 1; // This is to track numbers for each line
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)
  {
    if ($ticker <= $breaker) { 
          echo $i;
    } else  {
        echo '<br>';
        $ticker = 1; // Reset ticker
        echo $i;
        $breaker++; // increment breaker
    }
     $ticker++; // increment ticker
  }
}
 
print_pattern(20);


 ?>
```

Comment: Hi!, tysm for your effort, there is one missing thing here - the output starts from the right side while this code output starts from the left side.

Comment: @JonardanCena That is related to css. You need to align-right the text.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-align

Answer (score 1):

*Simple Approach:* Use just two loops one for rows which her index is `$i` and the second for columns `$j`, first loop loops through number of rows. and second loop will accumulate the result of `$k` which will be incremented on each loop.

```php
function print_pattern($num)
{
  $k = 1;
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)
  {
    $line = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++)
    {
        $line .= $k;
        $k++;
    }
    echo str_pad($line, 12, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo "</br>";
  }
}
```

**Result**

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_pattern(5);
/*
          12
         345
        6789
  1011121314
151617181920
*/
```

**Hint:** Use `str_pad` function to show the output starts from the right side.

Answer (score 0):

This is another method

```js
function print_pattern($num)
{
  $j = 1;
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)
  {
    $count = 1;
    while($count <= $i+1) 
    {
        echo $j;
        $j++;
        $count++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
$num = 5;
print_pattern($num);
```

another method