# PHP Number Pattern

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I've been trying to make this work but can't seem to make it work.

```
public function MarioFlagpole($a){
    $x = 1;
    if(is_numeric($a)){
    for ($i=2; $i<=$a+1; $i++){
      for($k = $a-1; $k > $i; $k--){
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
      for ($j=1; $j<=$i; $j++){
        echo $x;
        $x++;
      }
      echo "<br>";
    }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid Input";
      }
    }
```

The output should be like this if $a = 5

```
          12
         345
        6789
  1011121314
151617181920
```

But I keep getting this output

```
  12
 345
6789
1011121314
151617181920
```

Comment: Using counters of space characters is a terrible way of formatting any sort of textual output. If you're using HTML then I suggest using a CSS style padding instead. Or simply right align the numbers.

Comment: So your problem is text alignment? I don't know the algorithm that you are using, but I'm guessing that you'll need to calculate everything, then format afterwards.

Comment: wrap it inside <pre></pre>

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67723586/unable-to-get-the-correct-output-pattern-in-php It has the same pattern, and gives suggestions on how to pad it

Comment: Is this a classroom project? The issue and numbers in both questions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate numbers for each line and treat them as strings.
Collect all these rows in a `rows` array. Now, calculate the spaces for each line
by subtracting the current row length with the last row and that difference is those
many number of spaces. I usually prefer to use PHP CLI to check my output, but I am adding `<br/>` and `&nbsp;` for you to check on the browser.

```
<?php

function MarioFlagpole($a){
    if(!is_numeric($a)) return "Invalid Input";
    $rows = []; 
    $x = 1;
    for ($i=2; $i <= $a+1; $x += $i , $i++){  
        $y = $x;
        for ($j=1; $j < $i; $j++){
            $y = $y . ($x + $j);                        
        }        
        $rows[] = $y;       
    }   
    
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", strlen($y) - strlen($row)),$row,"<br/>";
    }
}

MarioFlagpole(5);
```

Comment: can you pls specify on what the use of each variables are. i'm a little confused since i'm new to this, I wanted to understand the logic that you did. thanks!

Comment: @TheNoobOne $x is a counter that just keeps incrementing by $i helping us with a start number for each row. $y captures all numbers in that row concatenated.